# Tensorflow version different in conda env & jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I created a conda env and installed tensorflow 1.4

```
pip install tensorflow==1.4
```

This installed, and from within the environment, when i type

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

it prints `'1.4.0'`

Now, i open jupyter notebook from the same environment, and when i type the same in the notebook, it gives me `1.10.0`

How is this possible? Jupyter notebook should take the same libraries within which it is running. How does it have a different version of tensorflow

And btw I'm concerned with this because i wanna use 1.4.0 in my notebook

Answer (score 4):

These are the questions I ask myself in situations like this, and they usually resolve my issue:

Was the kernel of my notebook running while I `pip`ped? Shut down and restart.

Are `pip` and `conda` sharing PATH, et cetera? I don't take it for granted that my pip is modifying my conda env. You can [check with these commands.](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-the-packages-in-an-environment)

Your conda env is created, but is it active? You [list created envs with these,](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments) and you can [activate/deactivate with these.](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)

Besides checking all of these, *where am I launching jupyter from?* I like to install jupyter with a simply `pip install jupyter` and that could add `jupyter` to the command line globally. Anaconda navigator/command line reliably launches the jupyter that lives in your Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Charles Landau:

You likely installed tensorflow in parallel with pip and with conda.

Within your env, just check with `pip list tensorflow` and `conda list tensorflow`. Most likely you will see two different versions.

To be consistent do:

`pip unistall tensorflow` to keep only one.